# sorting a list of strings as they are integers

Tags: python, sorting

I have a simple question of sorting lists based on values.
I want to order a list of strings as they are integers, and consider for sorting just the characters that are starting on second position.

As an example, I have this list:

```
L = ['X102', 'X201', 'X805', 'X111', 'X032', 'X155', 'X0123', 'X1113', 'X881', 'X1022']
```

if I sort it using `sorted(L)` I get:

```
['X0123', 'X032', 'X102', 'X1022', 'X111', 'X1113', 'X155', 'X201', 'X805', 'X881']
```

My struggle is to sort the list just considering the "integers", so just the numbers are after 'X' in order that the result to look like this:

```
SORTED_L = ['X032', 'X102', 'X111', 'X0123', 'X155', 'X201', 'X805', 'X881', 'X1022', 'X1113']
```

Comment: `sorted(L, key= lambda x: int(x[1:]))`

Comment: Someone find a dupe please

Comment: thanks - that answered my question

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a custom sort key using a lambda function:

```
SORTED_L = sorted(L, key=lambda x: int(x.replace('X', ''))
```

In this case, for each value in L, the `lambda` will remove the 'X' and convert to an `int`.